# FlexSlider flickers in IE8/IE7

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer, flexslider

I've setup a FlexSlider v2 carousel in a website. Oddly enough, upon the slider animating in IE8, the images appear corrupted until the animation ends. This only occurs in IE8/IE7, every other browser renders the carousel just fine (including the CSS).

I've tried removing all markup, styling and any other scripts apart from those needed and the problem still persists. I've also tried using JPG images that of thumbnail size, again it makes no difference (although there's slightly less flicker).

Any ideas?

Comment: Please add the relevant code and any examples if possible ..

Comment: Is this site by chance using bootstrap?

Comment: @Michael It's a site in Drupal 7. Using AdaptiveTheme as its base.

Comment: @Adrift Even with the example taken from FlexSider's demo page on the page, its bugged. Unfortunately, the site's not available on the web.

Comment: Here's a screenshot of what's happening: http://s21.postimg.org/r2bt3yvg7/screen.jpg

Comment: @trueadm Ok, this may or may not be a problem, depends on your theme.  I had a similar issue happen to me with this same plugin as well as jquery light on the same website.  Whoever made the theme added a line of code in the stylesheet that was causing massive animation problems, though this affected every browser not just IE8/7 - the code was: * {transition: all 1s ease;}  (plus all browser specific prefixes.  I commented it out and it worked great.  You may do a search for it and see.  This is a random shot in the dark though, sorry. =S

Comment: Figured what was doing it. The problem occurs when the slideshow loops; due to the nature that FlexSlider clones and removes items to give the appearance of a looping slideshow.